# How to execute Workfusion RPA business process using API call or using cmd?

Tags: api, cmd, rpa, workfusion

I am new to Workfusion RPA. 
I have created one business process from IDE and when i run manually it is working perfectly fine.

Now my Question is:
 1. Can we export any executable file so that i can execute it from command prompt?
 2. Is there any way we can expose REST api for that business process, so that i can call from any other application?.

please help in this
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

one approach you can take is you can schedule business process to continuesly execute and read a file from directory,cloud storage or sharepoint and you can write rest service or script to change a flag in the file that way you can control the business process execution if the flag is false bp will end in next schedule again it will read the file

Answer (score 0):

There is REST API available to launch and control business processes.

Documentation can be retrieved through such URL:

https://workfusion_deployment_hostname/workfusion/api/swagger-ui.html

`task_management` section, `/v2/workfusion/task/file` method. Request body can be as simple as this:

```
{
  "campaignUuid": "b8b95933-....",
  "mainData": "column1,column2\nvalue1,value2"
}
```